# Journey builder - testing and evaluating new contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm using an email audience as my entry source, and have the evaluate new records only setting as true. I attempted to test my journey yesterday, and nothing appeared to be happening, so I ran the journey events in automation studio, and the test appeared to work - the expected population appeared under all activities. I then  activated my journey, and it ran today at the scheduled time, however it didn't send to all contacts. It appears that it's only sent to contacts who weren't evaluated in the test yesterday. How do I test without impacting on the first send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an engineered flaw.

I talked to support about this a couple weeks ago.

When TESTING with an actual population when you have 'No Re-entry' selected, the journey will actually treat the TEST as if they have already been through.

2 solutions I propose:
1) is to change your re-entry criteria. Have to be careful on how someone qualifies to get back into the journey

2) is to duplicate your journey after the test and Activate the duplicate.  The duplicate doesn't carry over some information within 'decision splits' so if you have those, you may have to re-pair them.